# Delete everything on a webpage using a bookmarklet?

Tags: bookmarklet

I'm looking for a bookmarklet that when used completely deletes everything on a webpage. Any ideas?

EDIT: Follow up question, I need another bookmarklet that asks a prompt for text, then whatever you type in that prompt is then placed as text on the webpage...

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: As in it removes all elements on a page?

Comment: Have you tried googling? There are literally so many

Comment: Follow up question, I need another bookmarklet that asks a prompt for text, then whatever you type in that prompt is then placed as text on the webpage...

Answer (score 1):

You can use following bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(var element = document.getElementsByTagName("html"), index;

for (index = element.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    element[index].parentNode.removeChild(element[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
javascript:document.body.remove()
```